Does the series $\sum\limits_{n=1}^\infty \frac{e^{inz}}{\bar zn^3+|z|^3}$ converge uniformly on $[-2,0)\cup(0,2]$ or $[-2)\cup(-2,\infty)$?
I attempted to use the Weierstrass M-test:
Since $z=\bar z$ on all $A\subseteq \mathbb R$, we have, bounding the term from above,  $$\left| \frac{e^{inz}}{\bar zn^3+|z|^3}\right |\leq \frac{1}{|z|n^3+|z|^3}\leq \frac1{|z|n^3}$$
I do not see how I could've procured a different upper bound that would've been independent of $z$ terms on $[-2,0)\cup (0,\infty]$ since $|z|<2$, but I'd presume to say that the Weierstrass M-test fails here. What next? I am aware that the failure of the M-test does not imply non-uniform convergence.
Edit: As @Duong Ngo pointed out, there was a typo in the domains—they should should exclude zero. Following this, I believe that I can rescue the M-test strat since if $z\in [-2,2]\setminus\{0\}$, then $\exists \epsilon >0$ s.t. $\epsilon < |z|<2 \iff \frac 1\epsilon >\frac 1{|z|}$, so the M-test still applies. But this upper bound seems to be independent of the domain, i.e., it seems like it should hold for all $z\in \mathbb R$?

How does the series converge uniformly on $[-2, 2]$ when it is undefined at $z = 0 \in [-2, 2]$?

That's a typo on my part sorry. I've ammended the domains.

For the record, $\lvert z\rvert=\left\lvert\overline z\right\rvert$ is true even when $z\ne \overline z$. However, you have the first inequality backwards: it's $\left\lvert\frac1{a+b}\right\rvert\ge \frac1{\lvert a\rvert+\lvert b\rvert}$.

Are you sure that the M-test still applies?

For all $n$ where $n^3>|z|^2$, we have:
$$
|a_n|:=\left|\frac{e^{inz}}{\overline zn^3+|z|^3}\right|=\frac{1}{|\,\overline zn^3+|z|^3|}\leq \frac{1}{|\overline z|n^3-|z|^3}=\frac{1}{|z|(n^3-|z|^2)}
$$
This is close to what you wrote. But then we can pick some large enough $N$ so that if $n>N$ then, e.g. $n^3-|z|^2\geq (n-1)^3$. Using this:
$$
\sum_{n=1}^\infty |a_n|\leq \sum_{n=1}^N|a_n|+\frac{1}{|z|}\sum_{n=N}^\infty \frac 1{n^3}$$
$%\left|\frac{e^{inz}}{\overline zn^3+|z|^3}\right|\leq \sum_{n=1}^N\left|\frac{e^{inz}}{\overline zn^3+|z|^3}\right|+\frac{1}{|z|}\sum_{n=N}^\infty \frac 1{n^3}$
As long as $z\neq -k^3$ for any integer $k$, this converges absolutely. If $z=-k^3$ then the $k^2$ term of the series will be $\frac{e^{ik^2z}}{-k^3(k^6)+k^9}$ which is undefined.
